# Satispay without specifying the phone number

Tags: numbers, payment

I'm adding Satispay as a payment type on a platform but they need a phone number (the payment is based on that).
They have a JS script that shows a popup asking for the phone number but they still need one before opening it and I don't want to ask the user their number on my platform (I think is scary to give away my phone number on an unknown website and I don't think it is only me).
This is the [documentation](https://developers.satispay.com/docs) but I can't find anything about it.

Is there anyone who achieved that?

Comment: Probably you should use another payment solution if you don't want to stick to their rules.....

Comment: I don't "WANT", I have to. Is not my business but my chief. I HAVE to do this way.

Comment: ...and you think it's a good idea to do so? ;) Once again, if you (and yes, you asked for "I don't want to ask"!) don't want to ask your users for their phone number, but trick the system, it looks like a pretty obvious violation of their terms

Comment: I was asking because I saw a website do that but I can't find it to look at the code but I've found the correct way to do it and I've post it below.

Answer (score 5):

I'm Alessio from Satispay.

As you can see [in the documentation](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/docs.online.satispay.com/index.html#section/Web-Button/Parameters) data-phone parameter is not mandatory, [here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/docs.online.satispay.com/index.html#section/Web-Button/Code-sample) you can find an updated code example.

Answer (score 0):

I've just get that my autocorrector changed Satispay in Satisfy ... anyway the Satispay's docs are wrong, you don't need to pass a phone number using the Web Button:

```
    <script src="https://staging.online.satispay.com/checkout.min.js" class="satispay-button"
      data-key="your_key"
      data-amount='100'
      data-description="My Company"
      data-phone=""
      data-usercallback="https://url_to_create_the_charge"
      data-callback="js_function?transactionID=your_id_you_need"
      data-orderid="the_order_id"
      id="satispay"></script>
```

That is the correct way to create a Satispay Web Button call. DO NOT FOLLOW THEIR DOCUMENTATION (not until today) BUT USE THIS CODE!

Comment: Since you answered your own question you should accept your answer so the system knows to never bump this question

Comment: Hi, I have to wait 48 hours to accept my own answer :)